# NGRX Get State from Parameterized Selector in Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

### Background

I have an NGRX store for Search as follows:

```
export interface State {
   field: string;
   operator: string;
   criteria: string;
   offset: number;
   limit: number;
}
```

And because I have multiple uses of Search, I create multiple instances of this Search state in my main state object:

```
// In index.ts
export interface State {
    search: {
        main: searchReducer.State;
        other: searchReducer.State;
    };
}
```

And a parameterized selector to get the correct one:

```
export const chooseSearchInstance = (instance: string): ((state: State) => searchReducer.State) => {
    switch(instance) {
        case 'MAIN': {
            return getMainSearchState;
        }
        case 'OTHER': {
            return getOtherSearchState;
        }
    }
};
```

### Question

I am trying to implement some pagination on the searches so I need to use the above selector in an Effect in order to know whether it is still the same search or not. However, since "withLatestFrom" only takes an additional Observable source and not a callback, I am not sure how I would specify it in the Effect?

```
@Effect()
public searchItems: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType<searchActions.PerformSearchAction>(searchActions.PERFORM_SEARCH),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(rootReducers.chooseSearch( action.payload.instance)),   // <-- Cannot do this since there is no access to action at this point.
    switchMap(([action, searchState] => (/* ... */))
);
```

I also tried using a mergeMap that used this.store.select directly but it caused an infinite loop because this effect winds up modifying the state which triggers the selector in the mergeMap.

So how would I get a specific instance of the Search State to use in this Effect? (I suppose I will also accept answers that say this entire instance idea is wrong if there is a better way to represent different instances of the same type of state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue when trying to access action in `withLatestFrom`, this is how I got around it:

```
// Same as withLatestFrom but used mergeMap/forkJoin because of use of action.payload
mergeMap((action) => forkJoin(
  of(action),
  this.store.pipe(select(rootReducers.chooseSearch(action.payload.instance)), take(1)),
)),
switchMap([action, searchState] => (/* ... */))
```

Note the use of `take(1)` else the code will hang in my experience, it just takes the value from the Parameterized Selector. It hangs without it because I think `forkJoin` waits for all the Observables to complete, and `take(1)` takes one emission and then completes.

Comment: I don't seem to need the forkJoin, rather I did an inner `map()` inside the select's pipe and returned everything as an array.
I think the main thing was the use of `take(1)` which in hindsight makes perfect sense. 
Thank you.

Comment: sounds a good solution, if you could add your own answer to show what you did would be good so I can learn from it :) glad it helped